# Common interface for different OpenID providers and Facebook

Tags: php, openid, facebook, authorization

Is stack overflow using https://rpxnow.com/ for login in using different services? If so, is it good, and does it have good (preferable free, preferable with PHP API) alternatives?

What I'm looking for is a login page which would allow users to login using major web open-id providers + Facebook connect.

Comment: Please, please, please, use more descriptive titles for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, StackOverflow does not use RPXNow.  And if you choose to use it be careful to avoid [its pitfalls](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html).

I suggest you just accept OpenID, which covers many, many Providers (who uses Facebook but doesn't use one of Google, Yahoo, and (soon) Microsoft?).  Besides, I expect as an OpenID supporter, Facebook will eventually become an OpenID Provider too.  So I suggest you save yourself the trouble and just support OpenID using one of the PHP OpenID libraries since that is your language.

Comment: Interesting article on the pitfalls.  To me it's totally worth it...asking users to type in their OpenID url is a usability disaster (my parents don't even know what OpenID is, even myself a self-proclaimed geek couldn't tell you what my open ID url is).  Developing your own UI for that would be time consuming.  RPXNow provides a great service to startups I think.

Comment: I agree developing the optimal user-friendly login UI is very time consuming, and there is value is having a uniform UI that users recognize.  That's why I'm building a free one that can be hosted by each RP themselves: http://openidux.dotnetopenauth.net/   Check it out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

i remember signing up for RPX and being able to easily find a PHP example on their site.

Also, I don't believe stack overflow uses that, but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, www.clickpass.com is very similar to RPXNow. However, it also has it's detractors. http://notsorelevant.com/2008-03-11/clickpass-i-dont-get-it/